# How to determine what measurable sets look like?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

I have an outer measure on an uncountable set $\Omega$ defined by $\mu^\ast(\varnothing) = 0$ and $\mu^\ast(A) = 1$ if $A \neq \varnothing$. I need to then determine the measurable sets under this outer-measure.

I'm not really sure what this means though I assume it's evident. I know that to determine the measurable sets I should be thinking Carathéodory's criterion; i.e let $T \subseteq \Omega$ and then $E$ is measurable if
$$
\mu^\ast(T) \geq \mu^\ast(T \cap E) +\mu^\ast(T \cap E^c).
$$
So here if $E$ is a measurable set then for every $T \subseteq \Omega$ I need the inequality to hold, can I argue that if $E \neq \varnothing$ then for every $T \neq \varnothing$ the inequality won't hold as you get $1 \geq 2$? But then what? Does this mean that the only measurable set under this outer measure is the empty-set? What's the point of such an outer measure? Thanks in advance for the clarification!

Comment: Not quite: if you assume $\emptyset\subsetneq E\subsetneq \Omega$, that's when you get the absurdity $1\geq 2$. So the only Caratheodory-measurable sets for this outer-measure are the empty set and the entire set. What's the point? To make sure you know/are able to work with the definitions, and also it's good to check out edge cases.

Comment: Oh! I hadn't realized that because $\Omega^c$ is the empty set and so $\mu^\ast(T \cap \Omega^c) = 0$ and you get the $1 \geq 1$ case! Thanks, for the help! If you add the comment as an answer I'll accept it for the purpose of clearing it from unanswered @peek-a-boo.